# PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR: relation "posts" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I run rake db:migrate I get following output:

> == 20141219011612 CreatePost: migrating =======================================
> -- create_table("posts") rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
> == 20141219011612 Postposts: migrating =======================================
> -- create_table("posts") rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" already exists : CREATE
> TABLE "posts" ("id" serial primary key, "post" text, "release_date"
> timestamp, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in
> `async_exec' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in` block in execute'
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in` instrument'
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in` execute'
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in
> `create_table' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in` block in method_missing'
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in
> `block in say_with_time' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in` say_with_time'
> /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in
> `method_missing'

...

> `migrate' /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in` block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See
> full trace by running task with --trace)

I don't understund how this is possible, bescause In scheme file I don't have post table.

Comment: Drop the duplicate table in the Rails console. This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13299109/6594668

Comment: Please first check you database you have same table name exists if not then let me know. will give you solution

Answer (score 88):

Somehow, you ended up with a table named 'posts' in your database.  Perhaps from a prior migration that you deleted without rolling back?  If you don't care about any of your data in the database, you can run

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

to bring your development database inline with your current migrations.

If you have data in other tables you don't want to lose, open the database console and drop the posts table manually:

```
$ rails db

# drop table posts;
```

Then run `db:migrate` again.

Comment: but how is possible that there is no post table in scheme file?

Comment: I can't say without knowing the full history of all the steps you've taken.  It could be you've overwritten `schema.rb` with git or whatever source control you're using to an older revision.  Anyway, If you run `rake db:schema:dump`, `posts` will surely be in your `schema.rb` then.

Comment: Also, to be clear it's `posts` (plural) that is causing the error.  You keep mentioning a `post` table (singular).  I'm assuming that's just a typo on your part, and that you're actually looking for `posts` in the schema file.

Comment: thanks for second part, cause its always not a good thing to remove and reset everything.

Comment: @LeagEr, please accept my answer if it worked for you.  Thank you.

Comment: Type `\q` and then press `ENTER` to exit the console.

Comment: Postgres is the best open source database, hands down, possibly even compared to closed-source (Oracle, etc.).   I'm not a contributor, just a super fan.  #PGFTW

Comment: to drop a DB it needs this parameter  DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1

Answer (score 3):

**For those who didn't get your answer above**

---

In my case, I had been working on a feature a month ago the field happens to be created at that time. Now when I try to run migration `rake db: migrate` I see this error. I know and am sure that this is not here due to any mistake.

I also tried to rollback that particular migration

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20200526083835
```

but due to some reason, it did nothing, and to move further I had to comment out the `up` method in that migration file.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddColToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # execute 'commit;'
    #
    # add_column :accounts, :col, :boolean,
    #            null: false,
    #            default: false
    

  end

  def down
    execute 'commit;'

    remove_column :accounts, :col
    
  end
end
```

And, now I am able to run the migrations.

At last, I undo the commenting thing and I am done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your db/schema.rb

You most likely have the same table being created there in addition to a migration in db/migrate/[timestamp]your_migration

You can delete the db/migrate/[timestamp]your_migration if it is a duplicate of the one found in the schema and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I realized that I had been using a schema.rb file that was generated while using MySQL. After transitioning to Postgres, I simply forgot I would need to run `rake db:migrate` before I could use `rake db:schema:load`

Answer (score 0):

One of the hack I found was to put pry before you are creating the table on the migration file.

```
require 'pry'
binding.pry

create_table :your_table_name
```

and drop that table:

```
drop_table :your_table_name
```

After that you can remove the `drop_table` line and it will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

kill the current postgres process:

```
sudo kill -9 `ps -u postgres -o pid`
```

start postgres again:

```
brew services start postgres
```

drop, create, and migrate table:

```
rails db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will delete your data, don't do it on production.**
First remove the orphan migration `********** NO FILE **********` in case you have any, by executing this db command:

```
delete from schema_migrations where version='<MIGRATION_ID>';
```

then

```
rails db:schema:load
```

then

```
rails db:migrate
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the only thing that worked for me was to delete the table from within the rails console, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391724/5783745):

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:products)
```