# Getting a PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Getting a PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR and can't figure out trying what is wrong.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 6376
== 20170814192757 CreateRestaurants: migrating 
================================
-- create_table(:restaurants)
rake aborted!
 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "restaurants" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "restaurants" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character 
varying, "rating" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" 
timestamp NOT NULL)
```

Tried dropping the database and recreating it with the following.

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: Do you have multiple migrations which create a `restaurants` table?

Comment: Check your `db/schema.rb` file for a `create_table "restaurants"` block. The table must be created already by a previous migration. You can also check the db directly - run `rails db:reset`, then `rails db` to log into the psql console and then `\d restaurants` to see if the table exists and display what its columns, indexes, etc, are.

Comment: I dont know what I have done. I think I might have to start the project again.

Comment: ```rake db:drop db:create db:migrate``` is wrong you need to run ```rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate```.

Comment: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27558631/5783745) solution and it worked for me